# Adjusting line in Access VB

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've seen a number of question/answers on how to adjust the height of lines when the detail section expands; however, haven't seen anything about line width.

I got the line to adjust height by using:

```
Dim CtlDetail As Control
Dim intLineMargin As Integer

intLineMargin = 0

For Each CtlDetail In Me.Section(acDetail).Controls
    With CtlDetail
        If CtlDetail.Name = "Line192" Or CtlDetail.Name = "Line193" Then
        Me.Line ((.Left + .Width + intLineMargin), 0)-(.Left + .Width + intLineMargin, Me.Height)
        End If
    End With
Next

Set CtlDetail = Nothing

End Sub
```

BUT, while the line does adjust height the width reverts back to "hairline" rather than the points I prefer.

Thanks for any help I appreciate it.

Comment: You are using the `Report.Line` method, which only does hairlines. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.report.line --  I have the feeling that you want to do something else, but what?

Comment: I can use hairlines that's not a problem.  Is there a better way than the Report.line method?  My borders are 2 Pt and would like to be consistent.  I can change them to hairline.  Thanks